# Reducing the number of repeating same strings or integers to 1

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, integer

**Initial:**

```
 list = { null, 1, 2, null, null, null, 4, 5, 6 };
```

**Expectatitons:**

```
 list = { null, 1, 2, null, 4, 5, 6 };
```

Comment: Why would you expect sorting a list to make it shorter?

Comment: `Distinct()` doesn't work for you? Why? => https://dotnetfiddle.net/9uV7H8

Comment: So, you have have eliminated the duplicates by using `Distinct()`. What is your question? You can combine it with `.OrderBy(x => x)` or in .Net 7 simply `Order()`.

Comment: I reviewed my question and found that there is an error in my example.

my list is list={null,1,2,null,null,null,4,5,6}; expecatiton is list={null,1,2,null,4,5,6};

Comment: It cannot be. `int` is _never_ `null`.

Comment: Where are these expectations coming from?  Or do you mean this is what you *want*?

Comment: i convert int list to string list end the code, after i need reduce repeating null in string list.

Comment: Please update your question, so it is asking what you _actually_ want to know.

Comment: @ScottHunter thats private table game ,card desks algorithm part.

Comment: @Fildor jsut need repeating string delete in my list, i updated that question one sentence.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `list = { null, "1", "2", null, null, null, "4", "5", "6" }; ` @DmitryBychenko?

Comment: thats string list @Fildor

Comment: Exactly. That's what you said it _is_.

Comment: thats important for me i didnt find solution for that. I want to reach the result list = { null, 1, 2, null, 4, 5, 6 }; @Fildor

Comment: Yes, but you _cannot_. There cannot be `null` in `List<int>`. In `List<string>` it can. Assuming `list` is a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `list` is an *obsolete* `ArrayList` or `List<oblect>` you can try a simple `for` loop:

```
var list = new ArrayList { null, 1, 2, null, null, null, 4, 5, 6 };

...

int index = 0;

// Remove consequent null's
for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; ++i)
    if (list[i] != null || list[index] != null)
        list[index++] = list[i];

list.RemoveRange(index, list.Count - index);
```

To get rid of consequent *duplicates*

```
int index = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; ++i)
    if (list[i] != list[index])
        list[index++] = list[i];

list.RemoveRange(index, list.Count - index);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are removing items from a list, loop it backwards, so that the indexes of the not yet processed items remains the same.

```
if (list.Count >= 2) {
    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (list[i] == list[i - 1]) {
            list.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (list.Count >= 2)
        {
            for (int i = list.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if ((list[i] == 998) && (list[i - 1] == 998))
                {
                    list.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }   i convert your code like my want, thats work, thank youuu.

Comment: Side note: `RemoveAt(i);` can be slow if we have huge list and duplicates are in the beginning of the list: `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., n}` if we have a list of size `n` with `n / 2` duplicates in it's beginning we have to copy `n/ 2 * n /2` items, `O(n ** 2)` time complexity